# Flag declined, now I don't have flag options?

Tags: support, declined-flags

I was trying to flag [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853391/c-sharp-one-method-which-let-customer-pay) question as "Unclear" (aside, it has now been closed as such), but when the flag window came up, it warned me that my last flag was declined, and I should review it first.

Two issues with this. First, in my flag history page, it's not showing the 'last' flag was declined, or even any flags from today. The most recent flag that was declined was on Nov 3, the next to last.

Second, the flag window is only giving me options for 'spam', 'offensive', or 'mod attention'. Why are my choices limited on flagging this question? I tried on another question, and as given all the choices (as well as the warning), so why limit on this question?

Comment: You probably can't flag it as unclear because it's already on hold for that same reason.

Comment: I was trying to flag it before it was on hold, that was the flag I was going to use, and didn't have the option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In between the time when you loaded the webpage and loaded the flag dialog, the question was closed.

This makes sense, because the flag dialog options are loaded dynamically whenever you press the 'flag' button, so if you press 'flag' on a closed question only certain options come up. However, the content of the webpage doesn't update automatically, which is a rare edge case that generates an inconsistent UX state.

Note that while, for obvious reasons, I can't guarantee this is what happened, this is the only reasonable explanation I can think of.

Comment: That seems to be the case. I checked on another closed question, and the limited flag options are there as well. I had though it might be related to the declined flag warning somehow.

Comment: @CDspace Connecting it to the declined flag is reasonable with the information you had. For future note, though, declined flags don't actually have an impact on your flagging ability.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Any idea on how long the warning will be there?

Comment: @Emrakul Not necessarily true. 25% decline-rate with 10 flags or more in 7 days will net you a flag-ban until that condition is no longer met (unless something has changed recently). The warning is generated at 10%

Comment: Related to the ban: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Oh, huh, fair enough!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I can only find 3 declined flags going back to April 16, on two pages of my flag history. How is that 10%?

Comment: Ah, NVM, from the link "For users with less than 10 flags in the past week, look only at the status of the last flag"

Comment: @CDspace That check actually goes by *when the status was applied* and now *when the flag was cast*. So if an old flag from months ago got declined today, that flag would be counted towards your recently declined flags stats.